# lld-link.exe: error: failed to open a.exe: permission denied on windows 10

Tags: linker, llvm, permission-denied

i'm using lld-link to create a .exe file from a obj file but this happen:

[image: lld-link.exe: error: failed to open a.exe: permission denied]

I already searched for this error, the common answer was that a.exe was executed and that I have to close it , but I already search for it in the process explorer and there is no a.exe running. I also read that my anti-malware could be the problem so I turned it off but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write `a.exe` into `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin`. Either `cd` to your code directory before linking, or specify an absolute path for `a.exe` to be saved to in the `-out:a.exe` part of the command.